# WPF notify record locking to other instances of the application

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a scenario where multiple instances of the WPF application can be opened together. If a particular instance has made the data model dirty, I go and update the database saying that the current record is dirtied(I have a column in database that indicates whether the record is dirty or not). I want to notify the other instances that the record has been dirtied and no further changes should be allowed. Once the changes are made, I update this column saying that it is no more dirty.

How do I implement the change notification to other instances in MVVM way.

One approach is I keep a static variable isRecordLocked and check set if its false and then allow modifications.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called concurrency problem. There are two approaches you could take to handle concurrency problem - Optimistic locking or Pessimistic locking. I would encourage you to read more on those to get a better understanding of the problem. One article I would suggest reading is [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/OptimisticPessimistic.aspx)

My approach to solve this problem would be something like below:

1. First, add a column to the table. this would store the last updated date of each row. Let's call it LastUpdatedDate.
2. When your wpf app loads the data, all of them will have an original version of the row. Once users have made updates and hits Save, instead of setting a flag as dirty in the database, you could query to see if the value of the LastUpdatedDate column is same as when you loaded the data. If it is, you could just continue to save as normal. If it is not, you will have to inform users in someway (by throwing a concurrency exception and handling it on the UI) and ask them to reload the data.

Your approach of keeping a static variable won't work as far as I know. The reason being if it is a multiple instance of application, they will be in separate AppDomain and cannot communicate outside of that. So that static variable will be specific to each instance. However, if you have multiple client talking to a single server side, if you create the static variable on the server side, the approach would work.